# python manage.py runserver long start time

Tags: python, django

I have the latest version of pip, Python and Django, yet when I run 'python manage.py runserver' it takes at least 20 minutes before doing any system checks. I've looked on the task manage and the command prompt is using 0.1% of the CPU during this time. It also takes this long for me to run 'python manage.py migrate'. I seem to be the only one working on the project that has this problem.

Comment: Have you conferred with the others on the project to determine the possible reasons this may be the case?

Comment: Yes, they can't figure out what is wrong either. They have suggested reinstalling python and updating pip, both of which haven't worked.

Comment: Have you checked logs? Event Viewer? What OS are you running? Is this a work computer? If so, have you asked your IT staff? What about seeing what the processes are doing while they're taking so long to run?

Comment: Where can I find the logs and event viewer? I'm running windows 10. I'm using a personal laptop with an i7 processor. The CPU is doing nothing else basically while I am running this and rarely goes above 10% total usage.